R2 is good but not rmse , mse , mae
In my models, R2 in training and test sets are close to each other, but in RMSE, MSE, MAE of some models, these are very different?  what is the reason  Is there a solution?

Welcome to Data Science! How are you calculating $R^2?$

Thank you! I used merics.r2_score

In what sense are the RMSE and MAE bad but the $R^2$ is good?

Actually, there is a big difference between RMSE in training and test set!  Both R2 in test and training are 0.99, but in other metrics the difference is big.  which I think shows an overfitting.

I argue here that sklearn.metrics.r2_score is a nonsensical calculation when it comes to out-of-sample evaluation. Do your in-sample and out-of-sample means differ considerably? (Might you have some kind of data drift?)

@Dave No, there is not much difference in the in-sample and out-of-sample means.
